# Map local IP address to localhost

Tags: osx-yosemite

I have a site running at the IP address: 192.168.99.100 (This website is run by VirtualBox through Docker).

I want this website to be accessible remotely. I usually do this through PageKite which exposes the localhost (127.0.0.1) IP address to the public.

The problem is, PageKite supports only the 127.0.0.1 IP address.

I want to redirect the 127.0.0.1 IP address to 192.168.99.100. so that when I access http://127.0.0.1 on the browser I get http://192.168.99.100

Is this possible?

OS: OSX Yosemite